# Cannot upgrade git on CentOS6

Tags: linux, git, yum, perl, centos-6

I have

```
$ git --version 
git version 2.18.0


$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/WANdisco-git.repo 
[WANdisco-git]
name=WANdisco Distribution of git
baseurl=http://opensource.wandisco.com/rhel/$releasever/git/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://opensource.wandisco.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-WANdisco


$ perl --version

This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Copyright 1987-2009, Larry Wall

$ sudo yum -y update git
```

ends with an error:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:2.18.0-1.WANdisco.402 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: git = 2.18.0-1.WANdisco.402 for package: perl-Git-2.18.0-1.WANdisco.402.noarch
---> Package git.x86_64 0:2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl(MediaWiki::API) for package: git-2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(LWP::UserAgent) for package: git-2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(HTML::TreeBuilder) for package: git-2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DateTime::Format::ISO8601) for package: git-2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(URI::URL) for package: git-2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(URI::Escape) for package: git-2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl(MediaWiki::API) for package: git-2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428.x86_64
---> Package perl-DateTime-Format-ISO8601.noarch 0:0.07-7.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Params::Validate) for package: perl-DateTime-Format-ISO8601-0.07-7.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DateTime::Format::Builder) for package: perl-DateTime-Format-ISO8601-0.07-7.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DateTime) for package: perl-DateTime-Format-ISO8601-0.07-7.el6.noarch
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:2.18.0-1.WANdisco.402 will be updated
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428 will be an update
---> Package perl-HTML-Tree.noarch 1:3.23-10.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-URI.noarch 0:1.40-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-libwww-perl.noarch 0:5.833-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Zlib) for package: perl-libwww-perl-5.833-5.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl(MediaWiki::API) for package: git-2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428.x86_64
---> Package perl-Compress-Zlib.x86_64 0:2.021-144.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IO::Uncompress::Gunzip) >= 2.021 for package: perl-Compress-Zlib-2.021-144.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IO::Compress::Gzip::Constants) >= 2.021 for package: perl-Compress-Zlib-2.021-144.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IO::Compress::Gzip) >= 2.021 for package: perl-Compress-Zlib-2.021-144.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IO::Compress::Base::Common) >= 2.021 for package: perl-Compress-Zlib-2.021-144.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib) >= 2.021 for package: perl-Compress-Zlib-2.021-144.el6.x86_64
---> Package perl-DateTime.x86_64 1:0.5300-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Class::Singleton) >= 1.03 for package: 1:perl-DateTime-0.5300-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(List::MoreUtils) for package: 1:perl-DateTime-0.5300-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Class::Singleton) for package: 1:perl-DateTime-0.5300-3.el6.x86_64
---> Package perl-DateTime-Format-Builder.noarch 0:0.8000-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DateTime::Format::Strptime) for package: perl-DateTime-Format-Builder-0.8000-2.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Class::Factory::Util) for package: perl-DateTime-Format-Builder-0.8000-2.el6.noarch
---> Package perl-Params-Validate.x86_64 0:0.92-3.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl(MediaWiki::API) for package: git-2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428.x86_64
---> Package perl-Class-Factory-Util.noarch 0:1.7-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Class-Singleton.noarch 0:1.4-6.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.x86_64 1:2.021-144.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-DateTime-Format-Strptime.noarch 0:1.1000-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-IO-Compress-Base.x86_64 0:2.021-144.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-IO-Compress-Zlib.x86_64 0:2.021-144.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-List-MoreUtils.x86_64 0:0.22-10.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: git-2.20.1-1.WANdisco.428.x86_64 (WANdisco-git)
           Requires: perl(MediaWiki::API)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: I posted a question on Stack Overflow that I eventually deleted, but it seems like the WanDISCO URL 404’s out. Meaning it’s dead end.

Comment: Take a look here please: http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/git/x86_64/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like WANDisco has pulled both 2.20 and 2.20.1 from their repo from what I can see.

Personally, I've been skeptical why everyone is getting it from WANDisco anyway; doesn't appear they have interest in publically maintaining this.

You can follow a guide to compile from source here, just replace the version number:

https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-the-latest-git-version-on-centos

Actual source files are here:
https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/

And that's a dependable mirror that is mirrored in many other locations.

Comment: Note: just to add to that for completeness ... you'll want to remove your wandisco repo from /etc/yum.repos.d/WANdisco-git.repo  (or whatever you may have named it).